# Wake up light Arduino and Phonegap

Tags: cordova, arduino, alarm

So I'd like to make a Wake Up Light alarm system with Arduino and Phonegap. My goal is to use an arduino nano in combination with leds and a Real Time Clock module. Via a simple phonegap app I want to send the wake up time to my arduino and then the arduino will handle everything else.

My question is how to best send that data from phonegap to Arduino. I have considered:

- Using a Node server on a raspberry. This isn't really what I want to do because I would like to have as little devices as possible.

-Using bluetooth. Still, this isn't my preference because this would mean I'd have to connect to my arduino every time I go to sleep to set an alarm.

Does anyone have another suggestion for how to do this?

Comment: The last choice you have is wifi.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you dont prefer using Bluetooth, the feasible solution is to connect your arduino to LAN and give it a static ip, and then in the phonagap application at the alarm time trigger an event to send a signal to arduino to switch on the wake up light.